# ng-show and ng-hide inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have two buttons inside an ng-repeat. I want the following button to show if I am already following that person, else the follow button should show.

The two _.each functions are grabbing the followers info from another user

The followingList is the list of the people I am following

The problem know is that if i set the ng-show and ng-hide followingButtonTab to true, it does this for all instances of the ng-repeat. My question is, how can I affect one instance of the ng-repeat so the ng-show and ng-hide will change appropriately.

Thanks for any help!

**html**

```
<div class="follofwingBox" ng-repeat="user in following">
  <img class=" profile-img img-circle"  ng-src="{{user.img}}" || src="Assets/usericon.png" alt="User Pic"/>
  <div class="il">
   <span>{{user.name}}</span></br>
   <span>{{user.occupation}}</span></br>
  </div>
  <button class="follow-button text-uppercase btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-hide="followingButtonTab" ng-click="followTab()">Follow</button>
  <button class="follow-button text-uppercase btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-show="followingButtonTab">Following</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.following = []
  _.each(currentUser.following, function(id) {
    _.each(users, function(user) {
      if (id.followingId === user.$id) {
        $scope.following.push({
          name: user.name,
          img: user.img,
          id: user.$id,
          occupation: user.ocupation
        })
        $scope.followingLength = $scope.following.length

        followingList.$loaded().then(function(followingList){
          getitem = _.findWhere(followingList, {followingId : user.$id})
          if(getitem)
          {$scope.followingButtonTab = true}
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: you need to store followingButtonTab  for each user, as a property in the following array.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Thanks that worked!!!

Comment: if you don't want to add properties to the objects can also pass `user` to `activeUser` in controller and use `ng-show="user == activeUser"`

Comment: @claudia1201 if you got the solution working then post it for future references - or well, accept the Paul GR answer

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using a unique $scope variable to store the state of your follow button. All the buttons will have the same state, depending on how your last .each() iteration set your variable.

To solve your problem, you can add a boolean field in the object you store in your array (this will store a button state for each entry). Check this field inside each iteration of the ng-repeat instead of checking the global $scope variable, like this:

Template

```
<button ng-hide="user.followingButtonTab" ng-click="followTab()">Follow</button>
<button ng-show="user.followingButtonTab">Following</button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.following = [];
  _.each(currentUser.following, function(id) {
    _.each(users, function(user) {
      if (id.followingId === user.$id) {
        // Create the user object with a followingButtonTab field
        var following = {
          name: user.name,
          img: user.img,
          id: user.$id,
          occupation: user.ocupation,
          followingButtonTab: false
        };

        // Perform checking and store the result for each iteration
        followingList.$loaded().then(function(followingList){
          getitem = _.findWhere(followingList, { followingId : user.$id });
          if(getitem) {
            following.followingButtonTab = true;
          }
        });

        // Insert the user object in the array
        $scope.following.push(following);

        $scope.followingLength = $scope.following.length;
      }
    });
  });
```

It should work.